# clone link button next to Browse button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a link button 'Remove' next to the Browse button. Also clicking on the 'Remove' link should remove the 'Upload' input box and 'Remove'(cloned input). I would like to keep the first INPUT box and 'Remove' button and it should only clear the text from the Input box when 'Remove' clicked. I am new to JQuery, Could you please let me know if there are any suggestions.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var MaxFileInputs = 3; //Maximum number of file input boxs
        $cnt = 1;
        $('.add_field').click(function () {
            if ($cnt <= 2) {
                var input = $('#input_clone');
                var clone = input.clone(true);
                clone.removeAttr('id');
                clone.val('');
                clone.appendTo('.input_holder');
                $cnt++;
            }
            if ($cnt >= 3) {
                $('span.add_field').hide();
            }

        });

        $('.remove_field').click(function () {

            if ($('.input_holder input:last-child').attr('id') != 'input_clone') {
                $('.input_holder input:last-child').remove();
                $cnt--;
            }
            if ($cnt < 3) {
                $('span.add_field').show();
            }

        });

    });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<span class="add_field">Add</span>


<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="input_holder">
        <input type="file" size="50" name="uploaded_files[]" id="input_clone"/> <span class="remove_field">Remove</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What problems are you having? From what I understand from your description, you have it working properly. http://jsfiddle.net/w3HNz/

Comment: It's working but 'remove' button is not showing next to 'Browse' when I click on 'Add' button.